# Alternate colors for headers based on nth-child selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create alternate color headers without declaring various header styles to it. I decided to use nth-child selector for it and couldn't seem to create the colors that I need.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CRh6L/

HTML:

```
<h3 class="tips">Header 1</h3>
<p class="tips">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac purus neque. Nunc feugiat neque et eleifend lacinia. Proin a nunc imperdiet lacus placerat malesuada. Nam est libero, egestas sit amet leo nec, tempus placerat velit. Mauris pellentesque arcu eget pellentesque imperdiet. Mauris quis est lacinia, sodales nisl sit amet, dapibus ante. Ut quis arcu eleifend, ultrices tortor id, convallis arcu. Integer ut libero vitae dolor pretium porta. Phasellus sed bibendum lorem, in sodales tortor. Integer rutrum a orci non luctus.</p>

    <h3 class="tips">Header 2</h3>
    <p class="tips">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac purus neque. Nunc feugiat neque et eleifend lacinia. Proin a nunc imperdiet lacus placerat malesuada. Nam est libero, egestas sit amet leo nec, tempus placerat velit. Mauris pellentesque arcu eget pellentesque imperdiet. Mauris quis est lacinia, sodales nisl sit amet, dapibus ante. Ut quis arcu eleifend, ultrices tortor id, convallis arcu. Integer ut libero vitae dolor pretium porta. Phasellus sed bibendum lorem, in sodales tortor. Integer rutrum a orci non luctus.</p>


    <h3 class="tips">Header 3</h3>
    <p class="tips">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac purus neque. Nunc feugiat neque et eleifend lacinia. Proin a nunc imperdiet lacus placerat malesuada. Nam est libero, egestas sit amet leo nec, tempus placerat velit. Mauris pellentesque arcu eget pellentesque imperdiet. Mauris quis est lacinia, sodales nisl sit amet, dapibus ante. Ut quis arcu eleifend, ultrices tortor id, convallis arcu. Integer ut libero vitae dolor pretium porta. Phasellus sed bibendum lorem, in sodales tortor. Integer rutrum a orci non luctus.</p><br><br>


        <h3 class="tips">Header 4</h3>
        <p class="tips">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac purus neque. Nunc feugiat neque et eleifend lacinia. Proin a nunc imperdiet lacus placerat malesuada. Nam est libero, egestas sit amet leo nec, tempus placerat velit. Mauris pellentesque arcu eget pellentesque imperdiet. Mauris quis est lacinia, sodales nisl sit amet, dapibus ante. Ut quis arcu eleifend, ultrices tortor id, convallis arcu. Integer ut libero vitae dolor pretium porta. Phasellus sed bibendum lorem, in sodales tortor. Integer rutrum a orci non luctus.</p>
```

CSS:

```
p.tips {
    padding:10px 30px 20px 30px;
    font-size:14pt;
}

h3.tips {
    padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;
    font-family:OpenSans-Semibold, San-Serif;
    font-size:20pt;
    color:#E74C3C;
}

h3.tips:first-child h3.tips:nth-child(odd) {
    color:blue;
}
h3.tips:last-child {
    color:#C0392B;
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? I just need to get alternate colors for first and odd childs.

Comment: I believe your syntax should be "tips h3 {" and tips:nth-child h3 {".  Headings are secondary to the div.  Maybe tips h3:nth-child".  If you get no joy, try dt and dd instead.  Also missing comma on 2nd CSS declaration to separate first and nth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
h3.tips:first-child h3.tips:nth-child(odd)
```

use

```
h3.tips:nth-of-type(odd)
```

Your current code has `h3.tips:first-child` redundantly, since the first child is an odd-numbered child. Worse, you have a space between the selectors, instead of a comma, and this completely changes the meaning so that no element can match the selector.

Moreover, `:nth-child` is not suitable here, since there are elements between the headings. For example, your second heading is the third child of its parent (the first one is the first heading, the second one is the first `p` element). When you wish to match the odd-numbered among the `h3` elements, no matter what elements might appear between the `h3` elements, you need to use the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type) selector.